# Excel Ole Object Still Process List after quit

Tags: excel, delphi, process, ole, delphi-xe7

I have this code :

```
function XlsToStringGrid(AGrid: TStringGrid; AXLSFile: string): Boolean;
const
    xlCellTypeLastCell = $0000000B;
var
    XLApp, Sheet: OLEVariant;
    RangeMatrix: Variant;
    x, y, k, r: Integer;
begin
  Result:=False;
  //Cria Excel- OLE Object
  XLApp:=CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  try

      XLApp.Visible:=False;

      XLApp.Workbooks.Open(AXLSFile);
      Sheet:=XLApp.Workbooks[ExtractFileName(AXLSFile)].WorkSheets[1];
      Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam).Activate;

      x:=XLApp.ActiveCell.Row;

      y:=XLApp.ActiveCell.Column;

      AGrid.RowCount:=x;
      AGrid.ColCount:=y;

      RangeMatrix:=XLApp.Range['A1', XLApp.Cells.Item[X, Y]].Value;

      k:=1;
      repeat
          for r:=1 to y do
              AGrid.Cells[(r - 1),(k - 1)]:=RangeMatrix[K, R];
          Inc(k,1);
      until k > x;
      RangeMatrix:=Unassigned;
      Result:=True;

  finally

      if not VarIsEmpty(XLApp) then
        begin
          Sheet:=Unassigned;
          XLApp.Workbooks[ExtractFileName(AXLSFile)].Close;
          XLApp.Quit;
          XLAPP:=Unassigned;
        end;
      try freeandnil(XLAPP) except; end;
      try freeandnil(Sheet) except; end;
  end;
end;
```

but after quit with the Quit command, the process still remains in the list, considerations: I performed searches and understood that if there is a referenced object it remains in the list, but I believe that I have all released.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe.  Maybe a second after the app terminates, Excel disappears from the task list.  If you comment out `Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam).Activate;[...] RangeMatrix:=Unassigned;`  do you still get the behaviour?  If you do, then I would suspect that it is specific to the contents of your WorkBook, so readers could not help unless you could provide code to generate it from scratch.

Comment: Wow, I forgot to do in parts, I really did not try this, seeing now after commenting the actions I noticed that the Variable RangeMatrix that generates the error of getting the process open, would some function to clean it? without being just to set Unassigned?

Comment: I still can't reproduce your problem.  I don't think readers will willingly download a sample spreadsheet that could contain malware, so the only thing I can suggest is to add to your q the code necessary to generate a file which exhibits the problem.

Comment: the situation as a whole is:
I have a datasheet and convert it to a TstringGrid to view and subsequently update data, the above function I use in an If to start scanning:
`if XlsToStringGrid(sgrd_excel,e_arquivo.Text) then
    begin
// code here
    end;`

Answer (score 5):

Excel's `Quit()` command is not synchronous, it may take time for the process to actually exit.

And yes, you may have active object references. You are not clearing `RangeMatrix` if an exception occurs in your `repeat` loop, so it may not clear until `XlsToStringGrid()` exits. You should be using multiple `try/finally` blocks, one for each object.

And please, DO NOT call `FreeAndNil()` on `(Ole)Variant` variables! It only works on `TObject` pointers.

Try this instead:

```
function XlsToStringGrid(AGrid: TStringGrid; AXLSFile: string): Boolean;
const
  xlCellTypeLastCell = $0000000B;
var
  XLApp, WorkBook, Sheet: OLEVariant;
  RangeMatrix: Variant;
  x, y, k, r: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;

  XLApp := CreateOleObject('Excel.Application');
  try
    XLApp.Visible := False;

    XLApp.Workbooks.Open(AXLSFile);
    try
      WorkBook := XLApp.Workbooks[ExtractFileName(AXLSFile)];
      try
        Sheet := WorkBook.WorkSheets[1];
        try
          Sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell, EmptyParam).Activate;

          x := XLApp.ActiveCell.Row;
          y := XLApp.ActiveCell.Column;

          AGrid.RowCount := x;
          AGrid.ColCount := y;

          RangeMatrix := XLApp.Range['A1', XLApp.Cells.Item[X, Y]].Value;
          try    
            k := 1;
            repeat
              for r := 1 to y do
                AGrid.Cells[(r - 1),(k - 1)] := RangeMatrix[K, R];
              Inc(k);
            until k > x;
          finally
            RangeMatrix := Unassigned;
          end;

          Result := True;
        finally
          Sheet := Unassigned;
        end;
      finally
        WorkBook.Close;
        WorkBook := Unassigned;
      end;
    finally
      XLApp.Workbooks.Close;
    end;
  finally
    XLApp.Quit;
    XLAPP := Unassigned;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I did not know this restriction of the use of FreeAndNil, but even after the exchange of the function by mentioned the process remains in the list.
Maybe some specific spreadsheet content manages this?
note: I closed the application and the process still remains in the list.